# Highly composite numbers one less than a (prime) square

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

I noticed that a surprisingly high share of *small* highly composite numbers (i.e. positive integers with more divisors than any smaller positive integer) are one less than a prime square:

```
24   =  5^2-1
48   =  7^2-1
120  = 11^2-1
360  = 19^2-1
840  = 29^2-1
1680 = 41^2-1
5040 = 71^2-1
```

But then there is a gap: at least the 19 HCNs after 5040 (those listed by Wikipedia) are not p^2-1.

Is this just law of small numbers at work, or is there more to this strange cluster? Are there infinitely many HCNs that are one less than a square?

Comment: $a^2-1=(a+1)(a-1)$

Comment: In OEIS, you should find much more values. Usually, we won't have that both $p-1$ and $p+1$ have only small prime factors, which is necessary for a highly composite number. Seems to be a case of the "law of small numbers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the $\ 1000\ $ entries shown in OEIS, the only entry larger than $\ 5040\ $ which is a square minus $\ 1\ $ (and in fact the square of a prime minus $\ 1\ $) , is

$$17297280$$

I do not know whether any other examples exist. Any larger example must exceed $10^{77}$ , hence I do not expect other examples.

Comment: This is the $50$ th entry in the OEIS-list.